# bind an array of key value pairs to another array (nested array) in PHP ONLY

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an manager id who has various employees working under him. Using a query, i create a lists of employee IDs and is looping through it. From the employee Id, i wish to extract other details such as name,address,phone, etc. These details have been binded to an array($a) containing the key value pair.
The error occurring here is that i'm only able to fetch the data of the last id on the list(because the data is getting overridden) . 
I wish to store the data as (or any other easier way if u have in mind).

```
//Expected output
$a=([1]=>('name' => a,
          'details' => $details,
           'phone' => $phone,
            ),
[2]=>('name' => b,
          'details' => $details,
           'phone' => $phone,
            );)


// Code Implemented
$empoyeeId=[1,2] //assume to avoid query
foreach ($empoyeeId as $eid) 
{
    $data = array(    
            'name' => $name,
            'details' => $details,
             'phone' => $phone,
              );
    $result = array();
    $result[$eid][] = $data;
 }

return View('admin.edit', compact('data'));
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide something closer to your actual code.

Comment: move `$result = array();` before foreach

Comment: look at collection mapWithKeys. that might slove your issue

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get the data in an orderly way to work on it.

If it's a query, use Eloquent or Query Builder, applying joins and whatever you need.

If the front data comes, use Request $request and scroll through the object.

If you try to work with the format you have, you will have problems.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should help you achieve your desired output as stated in your question.

```
$finalArray = [];
$empoyeeId=[1,2]; //assume to avoid query
foreach ($empoyeeId as $eid) 
{
  $data = array(    
            'name' => 'example name'.$eid,
            'details' => 'example detail',
             'phone' => 'example phone',
              );
    $finalArray[$eid] = $data;

 }    
print_r($finalArray);
```

[See it in action](https://rextester.com/EVTO75834)

Comment: what is the use of temp?

Comment: @RKGUPTA whoops, I was writing this answer on mobile, and was playing around with optimizing the steps, this is a leftover from that optimization step,  I guess I missed that , there edited the answer